# jQuery drag image's viewport like Twitter

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have this div:

```
<div class="bgimg_div">
    <img src="userimg/<?php echo $row[7];?>" class="bgimg">
</div>
```

And this jQuery:

```
$(".bgimg").draggable({
    axis: 'y',
    containment: parent
});
```

`bgimg` height is always automatic. Now I want to drag viewport of `bgimg` like Twitter, but unfortunately my code isn't working because `bgimg` and `bgimg_div` are the same width.